# Convert 3.3 V PWM to 5 V PWM

Tags: voltage, amplifier, pwm

My Raspberry Pi 3b generates a 3.3 V PWM signal, but I need 5 V PWM for my motor driver.

Is there any chance to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the frequency of your PWM signal?

Comment: Please provide data for the motor and explain what power supply voltages you have.

Comment: Do you have 5V readily available?

Comment: greybeard, thanks for your comment, yes for the motor driver

Comment: (When you want a user notified, put a `@` before their name.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rpi's pins can't directly power a motor, as they have limited output current capability. You need to use a separate supply for your motor and command it with your Rpi; for example, you can use a simple logic level N-MOSFET. You have to choose the right N-MOS according to your motor current rating.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to run the motor directly using GPIO pins of Raspberry Pi, please be aware that the GPIO pins cannot provide a current of more than 16mA. If your motor's current requirement is higher, you'll easily destroy your GPIOs.

You need some sort of circuit to drive your motor, such as a simple transistor, or an H-bridge circuit if you need to change direction of rotation, too.

When driving the motor using a PWM signal to the drive circuit, you can simply use a logic-level converter. They are quite inexpensive and are easy to get. Most of these converters use BSS138 logic-level MOSFETs to translate signals from one voltage level to another. Here is a diagram to help you better understand.

[image: Logic level converter]

You won't face any problem regarding availability of 3.3V and 5V as you have those on the Raspberry header pins.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use a [TC1411](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001390F.pdf) for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy 3.3 - 5V level converter from Sparkfun

[Link to https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials...](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bi-directional-logic-level-converter-hookup-guide?_ga=1.28356604.1321603079.1492071175)